# My Array in java is out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a simple program for my grade 11 computer science and i keep getting an out of balance exception in my code. (see below for code)

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class project10 extends Applet
implements ActionListener,KeyListener
{

int width=1000, height=800; // screen size
Image backbuffer;
Graphics backg;
Timer timer1;
int degrees = 0;        
int shipx=40,shipy=800; 
int difficulty=10;  
int[] blockx =new int[9];
int[] blocky =new int[9];
int i;
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
        blockx[i]= (int)(Math.random()*1000+1);
        blocky[i]= (int)(Math.random()*150+1);
    }   


public void init()
 {
   addKeyListener(this);
   setSize(1000,800);
   backbuffer = createImage( width, height );
   backg = backbuffer.getGraphics();
   backg.setColor( Color.white );
   timer1 = new Timer(5, this);
}
public void start()
{
    timer1.start();
}

public void stop()
{
    timer1.stop();
}

public void destroy()
{
    //System.exit(0);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == timer1)
    {
        backg.setColor(Color.white);
            backg.drawRect(0,0,1000,1000);
            backg.setColor(Color.black);
            backg.fillRect(shipx,shipy,20,20);
            for( i=0;i<=9;i++)
            {
                backg.drawRect(blockx[i],blocky[i],20,20);
            }
            repaint();

    }
```

if anymore details are necessary just let me know and yes I did remove some methods

Comment: What is the size of `new int[9]` array? How many `i` values will be generated by this loop `for(i=0;i<=9;i++)`?

Comment: there will be 10 values added to blockx and blocky.

Comment: And how many values can `int[9]` hold?